# Microsoft Blend VisualState transition through intermediate state

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, expression-blend, blend

I want to create a transition from state A to state B through an intermediate state (where the lines that form the shape are compressed into a central dot)

As requested in the comments, below is a diagram of my desired end result.

The main issue here is that I have N starting states (here I'm just showing one), M ending states (here I'm showing 3), and I don't want to manually maintain N*M transitions. I'm ok maintaining N transitions into the "central dot" and M transitions from the "central dot"

[image: desired end result]

What i've tried so far:

1. Use **two separate transitions**:

The first one,

```
<VisualTransition From="Stop">
```

that collapses the "Stop" shape into a central dot, using animation from 0:0:0 to 0:0:0.5, and

```
<VisualTransition To="Continue">
```

that expands the dot into "Continue" shape, using animation from 0:0:0.5 to 0:0:1

Unfortunately, only one animation (To) plays. This leaves me with a need to create a lot of transitions for all combinations of To and From states.

**Is there a way to get both transitions to play at once?**

---

2. Use **Blend to generate transitions between the states**

When I pick a transition between two states,

[image: available transitions]

Blend generates a direct transition from one shape to another where the shape just scatters and looks terrible:

[image]

and I **can't add a keyframe** in the middle of the timeline (where the yellow line) where I would force all the lines to collapse into the central dot.

Also, I would like to apply "out" easing function from the intermediate state to the final state.

**How do I get Blend to respect an intermediate state?**

Comment: I don't suppose you have a more visual example to convey the intent by chance? This is one of those one's where simply seeing what's wanted would probably make quicker sense the explanation. Well personally anyway.

Comment: @ChrisW. I edited the post and added a diagram

Comment: Oh, yea that makes more sense, I've done those. What I did was just have `Scale` `Transform` on individual objects and toggle the visibility of stuff leave/entering once it got small enough the user wouldn't notice. Or would bring in a square or something over it so it "appears" to be a true transform. No need for any "middle" animation. I can show you tomorrow if I get some spare time.

Comment: How do you scale it down halfway through the animation and then scale back up? I can't create keyframes in the generated transitions, but if I load an existing transition, I can. The difference I see is that Blend uses `GeneratedDuration` property and `<VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>` element

Comment: Nah so say you go from Normal to MouseOver state, MouseOverState would would scale down the firs object for Normal State, and Scale up the new icon for the MouseOverState in the same animation sequence. I meant to ask, is this for a Button or anything specific?

Comment: I see, so for N states, you would use N *distinct* objects; in each state, only one object is visible, and all others are collapsed. This creates an illusion of shapes morphing into one another?

It's an indicator. There are many possible states which are changed by the code's logic.

Comment: Ya you got it, it would be just creating the illusion of an actual morphing occurring. I'm trying to eek out some time to try and give an example but it's a busy Friday and I'm heading out of town in a few hours for the weekend. You circumstance though could prove a bit trickier than I expected though considering I assume you'd want to flip from one state to another of many pretty randomly based on condition. Might take some pondering.

Comment: Thanks, that's ok. I see what you mean :) It's a smart trick!